# VFTF in Singapore for Indian Passport holder going to Canada

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, singapore, vftf

I'm traveling from Chennai, India to Victoria, Canada for my internship. I'm flying Air India from Chennai to Singapore and Japan Airlines from thereon. I'll be returning back to India in 3 months. Both legs of my journey have a layover of around 12 hours and I want to go explore the city. Will I be able get VFTF on arrival for both legs? Some websites stated VFTF can be availed only on the return journey. Would be great if someone who has travelled can clarify.

Comment: Your itinerary is unclear. The text says that on the way to Canada, you'll stop in Singapore. The text also says "Both legs of my journey have a layover of around 12 hours." How can "both legs" have a layover if you're only stopping in one place? Please also disclose your country of citizenship.

Comment: Sorry about that. My journey is Chennai-Victoria-Chennai with separate return tickets from Chennai to Singapore and Singapore to Victoria. And I have an Indian citizenship.

Comment: JAL implies that you are transitting through Japan, is that correct?

Comment: yes it's a 2 hours layover at Narita.

Comment: From the additional information you've provided in Comments, you have two separate return tickets. Ticket 1: Air India: Chennai > Singapore, and a later Singapore > Chennai return. Ticket 2: Japan Airlines: Singapore > Narita > Victoria, and a later Victoria > Narita > Singapore return. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's right.

Answer (score 2):

**I would strongly recommend getting a regular multiple-entry Singapore visa**.

The Visa-Free Transit Facility (VFTF) is intended for people who are connecting in Singapore on their way somewhere else.  Various online sites [claim that a single ticket is required](https://www.atlys.com/en-IN/post/singapore-transit-visa-for-indians), but technically, the [ICA only mandates an onward ticket](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-transit-depart/entering-singapore/visa-free-transit-facility).  However, you will need to convince not just the ICA, but the check-in agent for your Chennai-Singapore-Chennai flights, who will only see a return ticket that absolutely does require a visa. What's more, you will need to do this twice, since when returning from Victoria, Singapore will appear to be your final destination.  Getting a visa will make this much, much smoother.