# VFTF and Singapore Visa for Indians

Tags: visas, singapore, vftf

I am holding an Indian passport with a valid Canadian Visa. I will be going to Victoria from Chennai in two separate return journey tickets. I have booked Chennai-Singapore-Chennai return and Singapore-Victoria-Singapore return. My stay in Canada spans for about 3 months. I am unsure of availing VFTF on both the onward and return leg of my journey, which is why I am planning to get a Singapore Visa. However, by the time I return, my Singapore Visa will no longer be valid, and I will have to apply again, which kinda seems like a hassle, and I am not sure if that is something that is even possible. Can someone please clarify if I can avail VFTF for my return journey, or if I am eligible to avail it for both my onward and return journey.

Comment: Why repost your question, exactly?

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180943/vftf-in-singapore-for-indian-passport-holder-going-to-canada

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180943/vftf-in-singapore-for-indian-passport-holder-going-to-canada